# How to delete dictionary in nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested-for-loop

The example nested dictionary is:

```
x={'a': {'b': [{'mf': 1}, {'mf': 2}, {'mf': 3}, {'mf': 1}]}}
```

i want to delete the dictionary which contain 'mf':1

in this case the first one and the last one should be deleted

please help.

Comment: Which specific part of that are you having a problem with?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
x={'a': {'b': [{'mf': 1}, {'mf': 2}, {'mf': 3}, {'mf': 1}]}}

print(x)

for i in x['a']['b']:
  for key,value in i.items():
    if key=="mf" and value==1:
      x['a']['b'].remove(i)


print(x)
```

Output -

Before - {'a': {'b': [{'mf': 1}, {'mf': 2}, {'mf': 3}, {'mf': 1}]}}

After - {'a': {'b': [{'mf': 2}, {'mf': 3}]}}

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to have this new dictionary:

> x={'a': {'b': [ {'mf': 2}, {'mf': 3}, {'mf': 1}}}

Then you would need to first analyze the array and get the position of the dictionary you want to delete like this

> index = 0

> a['b'].pop(index)

You could try using the remove in the array as well but then you need to know which element to delete

> a['b'].remove('mf')

Also the pop works the same for the dictionary just give a key instead of an index.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_array_remove.asp